# Where are The Merovingian's quotes coming from?

Tags: dialogue, the-matrix-reloaded

In Matrix Reloaded (2003) there's a scene where Neo, Morpheus and Trinity meet with The Merovingian and Persephone:

The Merovingian is quite a philosophical character, here're some of his quotes from the scene: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0234215/characters/nm0933727

I would imagine that whoever wrote the dialogue was inspired by certain books - **does anyone know which ones?**

Comment: Is there any reason you think this specific character was inspired by a specific set of books?

Comment: Pissed French people, at least :P

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing discussion of this. Not that it would be authoritative, but I looked for a bit and don't see many essays/papers comparing the Merovingian's words to other writers (I did find a student paper making a comparison to Emerson). There might be something in the corpus of interviews with Lambert Wilson--I've never done a deep dive on those. I'll try to remember to watch those segments with commentary tracks on the off chance anyone mentions something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much of The Merovingian's dialogue stems from [The Principal of Causality](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/spirkin/works/dialectical-materialism/ch02-s06.html), which was actually a Marxist principal developed by Alexander Spirkin, a Russian philosopher and psychologist.

An excerpt particularly interesting is:

> The concepts of "cause" and "effect" are used both for defining
>   simultaneous events, events that are contiguous in time, and events
>   whose effect is born with the cause. In addition, cause and effect are
>   sometimes qualified as phenomena divided by a time interval and
>   connected by means of several intermediate links. For example, a solar
>   flare causes magnetic storms on Earth and a consequent temporary
>   interruption of radio communication. The mediate connection between
>   cause and effect may be expressed in the formula: if A is the cause of
>   B and B is the cause of C, then A may also be regarded as the cause of
>   C. Though it may change, the cause of a phenomenon survives in its
>   result. An effect may have several causes, some of which are necessary
>   and others accidental.

As you can see, this is the foundation of The Merovingian's quotes (on the page you linked) about causality, as well as time.